# Tips abouts comparing to database tables. Table Diff

Tags: sql, relational-database

Please share your tips about comparing tables :

- showing lines that contain the same values for a given set of columns
- showing lines not contained in table A but contained in table B &
  vice-versa

Answer (score 3):

I've always been a fan of Redgate tools: [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Provides very flexible options to compare tables/database with criteria based on rows, columns, filters, etc. e.g.

[image]

It's does for database tables what a diff tool does for text files. Especially useful when trying to identify difference between data constellations between dev and production servers for example. It also has a very handy feature to generate SQL statement based on the delta to apply the changes from one server to a second server.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, even if, at a first glance, it looks like a "Database server" comparison tool, to ensure that all the data in the first DB is also in a Backup or in a second DB, rather than a fine-grain table comparison tool...

Comment: I meant it is not straightforward to select two tables from the same Database and compare them. If you choose to compare a Database to itself (as choosing the DB is the first step in the comparison workflow), you will then be prompted by a list where a given table can be compared to ... itself. I am sure I must be missing a feature here, but wanted to share those first impressions.

Comment: SQL Data Compare certainly does a lot more than the basic case in your first question. But you did ask to share tips. This may come in handy for someone else. By the way, I'm not affiliated with Redgate in any way but I've used several of their tools over the years and always been extremely happy with the functionality and quality.

Comment: I have downloaded the tool. It has a very PRO feeling and integrates nicely in SSMS. It's ergonomic, fast. A pleasure to use it. Looking forward to diving into the FAQs & manuals to fully unleash its power.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the second part of the question:

> showing lines not contained in table A but contained in table B &
>   vice-versa

If you're using Oracle, you can use the [minus](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) keyword:

```
select field1, field2, . field_n
from tables
MINUS
select field1, field2, . field_n
from tables;
```

Comment: Other DBMS use the standard `EXCEPT` operator (which does the same thing as `MINUS`).

Comment: @Jacob Spire : works like a charm. The SQL Data Compare will probably provide more elaborate reports... Thank you all.